# Excel Macro to Change Color of a Row Based on Column and Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code and would like it to be modified to work on all worksheets in the active workbook. Also, it currently does the entire row, but is there a way to modify it to only highlight the row until the data stops (example: A-J or A-C etc. not A-~)?

```
Sub ChangeColor()

lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("A2:K2" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
    If cell.Value = "CENTRL DISTRICT" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    If cell.Value = "KC DISTRICT" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    If cell.Value = "NE DISTRICT" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 11
    If cell.Value = "SE DISTRICT" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 30
    If cell.Value = "ST LOUIS DIST" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 12
    If cell.Value = "SW DISTRICT" Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 13
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just use conditional formatting

Comment: How do you handle a scenarios where let's say `Cell A3 ="CENTRL DISTRICT" `, and `Cell C3 = "KC DISTRICT"` , where does each coloring starts and ends ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - good question, that hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: They are grouped by the district so it will only ever be all central then all kc etc.

Comment: @DefcaTrick so only one in a row ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below, you needed to change the range in the `if` statement.

You haven't given worksheet names here, but you should really fully reference all your ranges too.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MR = Range("A2:K2" & lRow)
    For Each cell In MR
        If cell.Value = "CENTRL DISTRICT" Then Range("A" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        If cell.Value = "KC DISTRICT" Then Range("A" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If cell.Value = "NE DISTRICT" Then Range("A" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 11
        If cell.Value = "SE DISTRICT" Then Range("A" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 30
        If cell.Value = "ST LOUIS DIST" Then Range("A" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
        If cell.Value = "SW DISTRICT" Then Range("A" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, It didnt go through every worksheet, but otherwise this worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note I have added declarations to your code).

```
Sub ChangeColor()

Dim lRow As Long, MR As Range, cell As Range, ws As Worksheet, lCol As Long
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

Set wf = WorksheetFunction

For Each ws In Worksheets
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set MR = ws.Range("A2").Resize(lRow - 1, lCol)
    For Each cell In MR
        If cell.Value = "CENTRL DISTRICT" Then ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        If cell.Value = "KC DISTRICT" Then ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If cell.Value = "NE DISTRICT" Then ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 11
        If cell.Value = "SE DISTRICT" Then ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 30
        If cell.Value = "ST LOUIS DIST" Then ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
        If cell.Value = "SW DISTRICT" Then ws.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Resize(, lCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
    Next cell
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: don't forget to fully qualify your `Rows.Count` and `Columns.Count` add `ws` as a prefix

Comment: Hello, sorry im new ish to macro, how would I qualify the rows and columns? also I ran yours and changed  the following because the districts are in E not A and it only highlighted E-H missing A,I,J,K...did I miss something?   Set MR = ws.Range("E2:E" & lRow) ty

Comment: Before I change the code, can I check if you are just checking column E for these values or can they be in other columns too?

Comment: They will be in column E and A however A is grouped, so it shows the name in A2 then blanks down to A52 where it gets the next district ...because they are grouped and can be toggled or rolled up by that column

Comment: Code amended above.

Answer (score 0):

This is simular to some of the above ... difference is it will hi-lite from the beginning to the last used column. It also cycles through all the sheets in the activeworkbook. It assumes the District Name is in column A.

```
Sub ChangeColor()

    For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    Sheets(x).Select

    lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Column
    Set MR = Range("A2:A" & lRow)

      For Each cell In MR
        If cell.Value = "CENTRL DISTRICT" Then Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, lCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        If cell.Value = "KC DISTRICT" Then Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, lCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        If cell.Value = "NE DISTRICT" Then Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, lCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 11
        If cell.Value = "SE DISTRICT" Then Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, lCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 30
        If cell.Value = "ST LOUIS DIST" Then Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, lCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
        If cell.Value = "SW DISTRICT" Then Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, lCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
      Next

    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will loop through all sheets in `ActiveWorkbook` (even though I feel strongly against using `ActiveWorkbook`), and per each sheet loop through `MR` range.

I've replaced your multiple `Ifs` with `Select Case`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeColor()

Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim MR As Range, Cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set MR = .Range("A2:K2" & lRow)
        For Each Cell In MR
            lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' <-- in case the last column is different per row
            Select Case Cell.Value
                Case "CENTRL DISTRICT"
                    Cell.Resize(1, lCol - Cell.Column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                Case "KC DISTRICT"
                    Cell.Resize(1, lCol - Cell.Column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Case "NE DISTRICT"
                    Cell.Resize(1, lCol - Cell.Column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 11
                Case "SE DISTRICT"
                    Cell.Resize(1, lCol - Cell.Column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 30
                Case "ST LOUIS DIST"
                    Cell.Resize(1, lCol - Cell.Column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
                Case "SW DISTRICT"
                    Cell.Resize(1, lCol - Cell.Column + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
            End Select
        Next Cell
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You can set a begin and end point to your liking just by changing the letters, which is a reference to the column letters. `Range("A" & n, "G" & n)` This is a simpler way to get what you want.

Hope I helped.

```
    Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim nlast As Long

    Sheets("sheetname").Activate
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        nlast = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                For n = nlast To 1 Step -1
                 If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "CENTRL DISTRICT" Then sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
                 If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "KC DISTRICT" Then sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                 If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "NE DISTRICT" Then sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 11
                 If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "SE DISTRICT" Then sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 30
                 If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "ST DISTRICT" Then sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 12
                 If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "SW DISTRICT" Then sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 13
            Next n
     End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this works great, thank you. Can it by any chance be changed to have something similar to the nlast but for columns?

Comment: So if one of these strings are found in a row, highlight the columns?

Answer (score 0):

i have made a similar thing to color rows in a table in Excel. this below algo is not much efficient but can make significant changes for it's optimization.

This will do your task.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Dim previousText As String
Dim interiorColorIndex As Integer
Dim fontColorIndex As Integer
interiorColorIndex = 48
fontColorIndex = 2

Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
    Dim newText As String
    text = Cells(i, 3).Value
    text = Mid(text, 1, 7)

    If previousText = "" Then previousText = text

    If text = previousText Then
        For j = 1 To 10
            Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = interiorColorIndex
            Cells(i, j).Font.ColorIndex = fontColorIndex
        Next j
    Else
        previousText = text
        If interiorColorIndex = 25 Then
            interiorColorIndex = 48
        Else
            interiorColorIndex = 25
        End If
        For j = 1 To 10
            Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = interiorColorIndex
            Cells(i, j).Font.ColorIndex = fontColorIndex
        Next j
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop
```

End Sub